# df.replace() leaving original values intact in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to standardize country names for merging with other dataframes. I've tried both variable reassignment and using the in_place param

```
df.replace(to_replace = {...}, inplace = True)
df = df.replace(to_replace = {...})
```

and both execute without errors, but leave the original values in place.

Just for clarity, here's what I'm passing into the function:

```
Energy.replace(to_replace={
"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
"United States of America":"United States",
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"}, inplace = True)
```

and the keys still remain the same in the original dataframe. I've seen some places in the pandas tag that the df.replace() function has some bugs, but I think that I might just be bunging something up here and not realizing it.

edit:
instantiated with:

```
Energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls')
```

and cleaned with:

```
Energy.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1'],  axis = 1, inplace = True)
Energy.columns = Energy.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
Energy = Energy.iloc[17:244]
```

for a data example:

|  |  |  | Energy Supply | Energy Supply per capita | Renewable Electricity Production |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | Petajoules | Gigajoules | % |  |
|  | Afghanistan | Afghanistan | 321 | 10 | 78.67 |  |
|  | Albania | Albania | 102 | 35 | 100.00 |  |
|  | Algeria | Algeria | 1 959 | 51 | 0.55 |  |
|  | American Samoa | American Samoa | ... | ... | 0.64 |  |
|  | Andorra | Andorra | 9 | 121 | 88.70 |  |
|  | Angola | Angola | 642 | 27 | 70.91 |  |
|  | Anguilla | Anguilla | 2 | 136 | 0.00 |  |
|  | Antigua and Barbuda | Antigua and Barbuda | 8 | 84 | 0.00 |  |
|  | Argentina | Argentina | 3 378 | 79 | 24.06 |  |
|  | Armenia | Armenia | 143 | 48 | 28.24 |  |
|  | Aruba | Aruba | 12 | 120 | 14.87 |  |
|  | Australia | Australia1 | 5 386 | 231 | 11.81 |  |
|  | Austria | Austria | 1 391 | 164 | 72.45 |  |
|  | Azerbaijan | Azerbaijan | 567 | 60 | 6.38 |  |
|  | Bahamas | Bahamas | 45 | 118 | 0.00 |  |

Comment: It should work as you've written it. Can you update the question with a minimal example of the creation of a dataframe with relevant values?

Comment: The above comment is not an edit to your question nor is it an example of your data.  Given that as a caveat, use ```df['Country'].replace(to_replace, inplace=True)```

Comment: @itprorh66 I just formatted it exactly the way you described it and it worked. I thought that I had tried that formatting, I guess I just bunged it up :))